# Getting "Unknown Column" error even though the column exists

Tags: mysql

I am getting an unknown column error:

> **1054 - Unknown column 'products_to_categories.products_id' in 'where clause'**

```
   SELECT `products`.`products_date_added`, 
`products`.`products_model`, 
`products_description`.`products_name`, 
`products_description`.`products_description`, `products_description`.`products_description_second`

    FROM products, products_description

    WHERE products.products_id=products_description.products_id 
AND products.products_id = products_to_categories.products_id 
AND products_to_categories.categories_id <> '91'or '46' 
    ORDER BY `products`.`products_date_added` DESC
```

The thing is that column exists. I even checked the spelling. So am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But it has a unknown table-prefix. "products_to_categories" is not a table you selected from in the FROM-Clause.

Add the table **products_to_categories** to your FROM part.

```
… FROM products, products_description, products_to_categories ...
```